# Email hosting without changing nameservers or adding A record

Tags: email, smtp, hosting, web-hosting, mailgun

Recently I have created a website for a client using Laravel/PHP. and then hosted on a cloud hosting provider vultr.com, the client didn't give me access to their domain (abc.com). they just pointed the domain to new hosting and the site is live.

The problem came when I wanted to configure email SMTP. I am using Mailgun for the emails. but for using service like mailgun you have to changes the nameservers in the domain setting. in my case, the client doesn't want to use the domain (abc.com) for emails because the domain is in their owner's name. so they are not changing the nameservers.

So my question is their anyways that I use some other domain or service for sending emails but
not the domain abc.com which is pointed to my hosting.

Also, they don't want to add the A record in the domain. the client just doesn't want to use the same domain for emails.

I hope I made my point clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Case 1, You can create a subdomain and use dedicated for email like mail.domain.com, in subdomain update DNS recode and use for delivery its also not affect your main domain, in case you use sub email as abc@mail.domain.com for your emails.

Case 2, also an  option to use the different domain name for emails and update DNS recode like PTR and DKIM, PTR, SPF